# What are my options if I have gems with conflicting dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, padrino

I am trying to get a sample project up and running in Padrino using Mongoid.  I was getting an error when running bundle because padrino required 3.0.8 of activesupport, and mongoid required 3.0.5.  So I gem installed 3.0.5 and I was able to run bundle.  But now when I try to create a new model like

```
padrino g model post title:string body:text
```

I get this error

```
=> Problem loading ./config/boot.rb
=> You have already activated activesupport 3.0.8, but your 
Gemfile requires activesupport 3.0.5. Consider using bundle exec.
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade rubygems, they might allow it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a little problem at the moment with bundler and Active* dependencies, so force it to be `gem 'activesupport', '~>3.0.11', :require => 'active_support'`